# Seeing rand() from a class and comparing user input to the computers choice. Rock, paper, scissor game

Tags: c++

I submitted this code incomplete to my instructor just so I'd get a 'timeliness' grade on it. That being said, I don't want to give up on this game because I've really been struggling to figure out how to complete it plus I can resubmit it for a better score. When I submitted it, the only feedback I got on it was: "int randNum = rand() % 5 + 1; This is what a constructor is for. You didn't seed it. This doesn't work." I think I fixed that. But that is not the only problem with this: A) I don't have a way to keep score B) There is not a way to keep track of the rounds played C) A way to compare the user input to the computers'. A,B and C are what I've been focusing on for a few days with no progress. Any advice or tips would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;





class ComputersChoice { //Class that contains the random number function for the AI player
    private:
        int randNum;

    public:

        ComputersChoice() {
            randNum = value();
        }
        int GetChoice() {
            return randNum;
        }
        int value() {
            randNum = rand() % 5 + 1;
            return randNum;
        }


        void printResult() {
        if (randNum == 1) {
            cout <<"The computer chose rock.";
        }

        else if (randNum == 2) {
            cout<<"The computer chose paper.";
        }

        else if (randNum == 3) {
            cout<<"The computer chose scissors.";
        }

        else if (randNum == 4) {
            cout<<"The computer chose lizard.";
        }    

        else {
            cout<<"The computer chose spock.";
        }    


        }       
};





//How many rounds does the user want to play function
int GetRounds() {  

    bool isValid = false;

    int rounds = 0;

    while (!isValid) {

    cout<<"Do you want to play 3, 5 or 7 rounds?" << endl;
    cin>>rounds;

    switch(rounds) {
        case 3:
        case 5: 
        case 7:
           isValid = true;
           break;
        default:
            cout<<"Invalid input. Enter 3, 5 or 7."<<endl;
            break;

}

}

    cout<<"You picked the best of " << rounds << " rounds." << endl;
        return rounds;

}    

//User input
int GetUser() {

    int user_choice = 0;

    cout<<"Enter 1 for rock, 2 for paper, 3 for scissors, 4 for lizard, 5 for spock." << endl;
    cin>>user_choice;

    if (user_choice == 1) {
        cout<<"You chose rock. ";
    }

    else if (user_choice == 2) {
        cout<<"You chose paper. ";
    }

    else if (user_choice == 3) {
        cout<<"You chose scissors. ";
    }

    else if (user_choice == 4) {
        cout<<"You chose lizard. ";
    }

    else if (user_choice == 5) {
        cout<<"You chose spock. ";
    }

    else {
        cout<<"Enter a valid value.";
    }

}





int main() {
    GetRounds();
    GetUser();


    srand(time(NULL));

    ComputersChoice A;
    A.printResult();




}
```

Comment: Here's a tip: take a blank piece of paper and a pen. Write down in short, logical sentences, what you want your program to do. After [discussing your proposed course of action with your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), simply take what you wrote down and translate it directly into C++ code. Mission accomplished.

Comment: Your class structure is off, I think.  ComputerChoice isn't a class.   A choice is.  user choice and computer choice are just instances.   You'd then have two functions to generate the input for the choices.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I went ahead and modified your code into a fully functioning Rock Paper Scissors Lizard Spock game, heres the code:

```
#include <iostream>

// Class that contains the random number function for the AI player
// And runs the rest of the RockPaperScissors game.
class RockPaperScissors {
 private:
    int rand_num;
    int number_of_rounds;
    int user_choice;
    int player_wins;
    int computer_wins;

 public:
    RockPaperScissors() {}

    // Prints computers choice, decided by rand_r
    void printComputerChoice();
    // How many rounds does the user want to play function
    void getRounds();
    // Get user input for the game
    void getUserChoice();
    // Calculate the result of the round
    int calculateResult();
    // Runs the game
    void run();
};

void RockPaperScissors::printComputerChoice() {
    std::cout << "The computer chose ";
    switch (rand_num) {
        case 1:
            std::cout << "rock.";
            break;
        case 2:
            std::cout << "paper.";
            break;
        case 3:
            std::cout << "scissors.";
            break;
        case 4:
            std::cout << "lizard.";
            break;
        case 5:
            std::cout << "spock.";
            break;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void RockPaperScissors::getRounds() {
    number_of_rounds = 0;
    std::cout << "Do you want to play 3, 5 or 7 rounds?" << std::endl;
    while (true) {
        std::cin >> number_of_rounds;
        if (std::cin.fail())
            std::cin.clear(), std::cin.ignore(256, '\n');
        if (number_of_rounds == 3 || number_of_rounds == 5
                || number_of_rounds == 7) {
            std::cout << "You picked the best of "
                << number_of_rounds << " rounds." << std::endl;
            return;
        }
        std::cout << "Invalid input. Enter 3, 5 or 7." << std::endl;
    }
}

void RockPaperScissors::getUserChoice() {
    user_choice = 0;
    std::cout << "Enter 1 for rock, 2 for paper, 3 for scissors,"
        << " 4 for lizard, 5 for spock." << std::endl;
    while (user_choice == 0) {
        std::cin >> user_choice;
        if (std::cin.fail())
            std::cin.clear(), std::cin.ignore(256, '\n');
        std::cout << "You chose ";
        switch (user_choice) {
            case 1:
                std::cout << "rock.";
                break;
            case 2:
                std::cout << "paper.";
                break;
            case 3:
                std::cout << "scissors.";
                break;
            case 4:
                std::cout << "lizard.";
                break;
            case 5:
                std::cout << "spock.";
                break;
            default:
                user_choice = 0;
                std::cout << "a non-valid value, enter 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5.";
                break;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return;
}

int RockPaperScissors::calculateResult() {
    switch (user_choice) {
        case 1:  // rock
            switch (rand_num) {
                case 1:  // rock
                    return 0;
                    break;
                case 2:  // paper
                    return -1;
                    break;
                case 3:  // scissors
                    return 1;
                    break;
                case 4:  // lizard
                    return 1;
                    break;
                case 5:  // spock
                    return -1;
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case 2:  // paper
            switch (rand_num) {
                case 1:  // rock
                    return 1;
                    break;
                case 2:  // paper
                    return 0;
                    break;
                case 3:  // scissors
                    return -1;
                    break;
                case 4:  // lizard
                    return -1;
                    break;
                case 5:  // spock
                    return 1;
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case 3:  // scissors
            switch (rand_num) {
                case 1:  // rock
                    return -1;
                    break;
                case 2:  // paper
                    return 1;
                    break;
                case 3:  // scissors
                    return 0;
                    break;
                case 4:  // lizard
                    return -1;
                    break;
                case 5:  // spock
                    return 1;
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case 4:  // lizard
            switch (rand_num) {
                case 1:  // rock
                    return -1;
                    break;
                case 2:  // paper
                    return 1;
                    break;
                case 3:  // scissors
                    return 1;
                    break;
                case 4:  // lizard
                    return 0;
                    break;
                case 5:  // spock
                    return -1;
                    break;
            }
        case 5:  // spock
            switch (rand_num) {
                case 1:  // rock
                    return 1;
                    break;
                case 2:  // paper
                    return -1;
                    break;
                case 3:  // scissors
                    return -1;
                    break;
                case 4:  // lizard
                    return 1;
                    break;
                case 5:  // spock
                    return 0;
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }
}

void RockPaperScissors::run() {
    number_of_rounds = 0;
    user_choice = 0;
    player_wins = 0;
    computer_wins = 0;
    getRounds();
    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_rounds; i++) {
        unsigned int seed = time(NULL);
        rand_num = rand_r(&seed) % 5 + 1;
        getUserChoice();
        printComputerChoice();
        int result = calculateResult();
        if (result == 1) {
            player_wins++;
            std::cout << "Win!!" << std::endl;
        } else if (result == -1) {
            computer_wins++;
            std::cout << "Loss!" << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << "TIE!!" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    if (player_wins > computer_wins)
        std::cout << "You won! " << player_wins << " to "
            << computer_wins << std::endl;
    else if (player_wins == computer_wins)
        std::cout << "It was a TIE! " << player_wins << " to "
            << computer_wins << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "You lost :( " << computer_wins << " to "
            << player_wins << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    RockPaperScissors game;
    while (true) {
        game.run();
        std::cout << "Would you like to keep playing? (y)/n" << std::endl;
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(256, '\n');
        if (std::cin.get() == 'n')
            break;
        std::cin.ignore(256, '\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

First of all I changed the name of the class to represent the entire game. Let's start inside the class `RockPaperScissors` -- I added a few new private variables, `number_of_rounds` `user_choice` `player_wins` and `computer_wins`. I added `number_of_rounds` because we are now keeping the number of rounds the user wants to play inside the `RockPaperScissors` class. `user_choice` keeps track of what the player has chosen. `player_wins` and `computer_wins` keep track of the number of wins between each.

Now for the functions, your teacher said that's what constructors are for because you made a function to call from you constructor when you should have just put the code in the constructor, however, I moved that to a function called run because we wanted to be able to run the game over and over again.

The first function we'll go over is `void run()`, the first thing I did was initialized all of the variables, this will happen each time run is called so we didn't want this to be in the constructor. Next, I call `getRounds` let's go into there.

So in `getRounds` first we set `number_of_rounds` to 0, which isn't exactly necessary but it's nice to have there, then we tell the user to input a number. We call `std::cin >> number_of_rounds` and if the user types in a number it works fine and dandy but if the user types in something like a letter instead the following happens. `number_of_rounds` is set to 0, `std::cin`'s fail bit is set and will continue to return 0 until fixed, the solution is we `clear()` then `ignore(256,'\n')` until the end of the line to reset all of that safely, and then tell them they need to input a valid number. If they don't do that and they pick a valid number it goes to the if statement.

Previously you had used a `switch` statement here, this was entirely unnecessary because it was much more easily replaced with a single if statement like such `if (number_of_rounds == 3 || number_of_rounds == 5 || number_of_rounds == 7)` and if you didn't know `||` essentially means 'or'.

Let's go back to the `run` function. The next thing we do is create a `for` loop which lets us loop through the number of rounds there are. Inside this loop, we create a seed that is passed to `rand_r` that gives us our number for `rand_num`. Then, we get the user's choice in the function `getUserChoice` so let's go there.

First thing we do is reset `user_choice` to 0, here that's actually helpful because our `while` loop won't run if it's not 0. Then we tell the user to input a choice for their weapon if you will. Inside the `while (user_choice == 0) {` we call `std::cin >> user_choice` so of course, since we're using `std::cin` to get input directly to an int variable we need to make sure that if the user types in a non int value that `std::cin` is useable again, so we do that part again.

On this next part you had used a bunch of if-else-if statements and they all had two things in common, the "You chose " part and the space at the end, which I opted for a newline. Now I could have also taken the period and moved it down there but I just didn't. So what I did was I moved those repeated parts to the outsides of the conditionals so they only have to happen once. Then I replaced your if-else-if statements with a switch statement because it looks better, in this situation, and is supposedly faster.

Next in `run` we call `printComputerChoice()`. All I really did here was move the repeated parts to the outside of the conditional statements and changed the if-else-if statements to switch statements.

Finally, we're calculating the result in the function `calculateResult` that returns `int`. -1 for Loss, 0 for Tie, and 1 for Win. In this function, I used nested switch statements which I believe aren't too hard to read and are probably easier to read than a nested if version.

After we've gotten our value from `calculateResult`, we check if the result was 1, if so then `player_wins++` and tell the user they won the round. If result was 0 just tell the player it was a tie. Else(only other option is -1) then `computer_wins++` and tell the user they lost the round.

At the end of the function, outside the loop, check if the player or the computer had a higher score or if they were the same and alert the player respectively.

And last but not least, a quick explanation of the `main` function:

1. Create the game
2. Implement a while loop that goes forever
3. Run the game
4. The game is over so let's ask the user if they want to play again
5. First let's clear `std::cin`
6. There will have been left over characters and a '\n' so let's clear that out of `std::cin`
7. Get a character from `std::cin` if it is 'n' `break`, if it's anything else just keep playing
8. `std::cin.get` only got one character from the stream so let's get rid of the rest in the stream.